# Как сделать так, чтобы элементы при использовании transform: scale прижималась к верхнему левому краю?

Tags: html

Изначальное размещение элементов:

[image: Пример начального расположения элементов]

Размещение после применения transform: scale

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, элементы сместились. Как этого не допустить? Как изменить размеры элементов, не изменяя их расположение?

Comment: они по любому будут смещаться, только куда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно указать точку трансформации: `transform-origin`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block__content {
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.block:hover .block__content {
  transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__content">
  Контент Контент Контент Контент Контент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент
  КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент КонтентКонтент Контент
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то, что мне нужно!